# Preventing list objects from being processed twice when using a java threadpool

Tags: java, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Lets say i have a list of 10,000 objects

```
ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();  
al.add("1");  
al.add("2");
al.add("..");  
al.add("10000");
```

I want to process the 10,000 objects using a thread pool with 20 threads.The goal is to ensure that my program reads every object exactly once.

Since the program wont be marking that a list object has been read, am i guaranteed that every object shall only be processed once?.

Comment: Put all 10.000 objects in a ConcurrentLinkedQueue then, in each processing thread, use ConcurrentLinkedQueue.poll to retrieve the objects.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea and it may indeed be stupid. Since you are only attempting to read objects in a list, how about if you apply this strategy.

1. You have 10000 elements in list.
2. You have 20 Threads.
3. Each thread picks 500 elements.
4. For each thread you assign an integer id like 1 to 20.
5. Each thread accesses elements based upon their integer id.
6. Like thread 1 access from 0-499.
7. Similarly thread 2 access from 500-999 and so on.
8. This will guarantee you that no element will be read by multiple threads.
9. One assumption here, that all threads will be doing similar kind of processing on elements.

And in another approach, what you could do is, create a Synchronized Set and everytime you pick an element, check if the index is present in the set or not and if not present, pick the element and insert its index into the set. This way you will not pick an element twice.

Answer (score 0):

U can using this code :

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //add item in here and remember using sync data
    }
});
executorService.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide the list into 20 parts:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> mapList = al.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i.hashCode() % 20));
```